# How to change the on_press function through another function ? (python,kivy)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am programming a currency converter just for fun and to learn something more about python. I'm trying to change the on_press function of the "calculate"- button throught the on_press function of the"swap"-button. With this I'm trying to change direction of the calculation.
Here is the code:
python-file:

```
class Waehrungsrechner(BoxLayout):    
    def swap_GBP(self,*args):
        GBP_textleft = self.ids.GBP_textleft
        GBP_textright = self.ids.GBP_textright
        textleft = GBP_textleft.text
        textright = GBP_textright.text
        BTN_calc = self.ids.GBP_calc

        direction = -1

        if textleft == "Euro":
            direction = 1
        elif textleft == "Britisches Pfund":
            direction = 2

        if direction == 1:
            GBP_textleft.text = "Britisches Pfund"
            GBP_textright.text = "Euro"
            BTN_calc.bind(on_press = Waehrungsrechner.calculate_GBP2())
            direction = 2
        elif direction == 2:
            GBP_textleft.text = "Euro"
            GBP_textright.text = "Britisches Pfund"
            BTN_calc.bind(on_press = Waehrungsrechner.calculate_GBP1())
            direction = 1


    def calculate_GBP1(self,*args):

        Input = self.ids.GBP_Input
        label = self.ids.GBP_Ergebnis
        access = True
        try:
            Eingabe = float(Input.text)
        except:
            label.text = "Error"
            access = False

        if access == True:
            Ergebnis = "{0:.2f}".format(Eingabe*GBP_valuef)
            label.text = str(Ergebnis)

    def calculate_GBP2(self,*args):

        Input = self.ids.GBP_Input
        label = self.ids.GBP_Ergebnis
        access = True
        try:
            Eingabe = float(Input.text)
        except:
            label.text = "Error"
            access = False

        if access == True:
            Ergebnis = "{0:.2f}".format(Eingabe*(1/GBP_valuef))
            label.text = str(Ergebnis)


class WaehrungsrechnerApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Waehrungsrechner();

Waehrungsrechner1 = WaehrungsrechnerApp()
Waehrungsrechner1.run()
```

kv-file:

```
<Waehrungsrechner>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: "Waehrungsrechner"
        font_size: 60
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 200


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                id: GBP_textleft
                text: "Euro"
                font_size: 30

            TextInput:
                id: GBP_Input
                font_size: 25
                multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Button:
                id: GBP_calc
                text: "Berechne"
                font_size : 20
                on_press: root.calculate_GBP1()

            Button:
                text: "<-->"
                font_size: 20
                on_press: root.swap_GBP()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'         

            Label:
                id: GBP_textright
                text: "Britisches Pfund"
                font_size: 30

            Label:
                id: GBP_Ergebnis
                text: ""
                font_size: 30

    TextInput:
        font_size: 30
        multiline: False
```

it shows: calculate_GBP2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 1):

One must access the method of a class through the object, in your case it is `self`, unless it is a `staticmethod`, In addition, the `bind()` method requires the name of the function, not the evaluated function, so it eliminates the parentheses.

You must change:

```
BTN_calc.bind(on_press = Waehrungsrechner.calculate_GBP2())
...
BTN_calc.bind(on_press = Waehrungsrechner.calculate_GBP1())
```

to:

```
BTN_calc.bind(on_press = self.calculate_GBP2)
...
BTN_calc.bind(on_press = self.calculate_GBP1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I already tried this yesterday and i dont get an error message  but the calculation doesn't work. Is there maybe another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's now using both functions  and the first one is overwriting the result of the second one (when adding print). How can I unbind the function from the button?